# How to traverse through JSON data for specific items in Django

Tags: json, django

I am attempting to convert locations to geocode to be stored for listings. I am using a 3rd party API that returns JSON after a location such as a city/state or zip code is used.

I would like to:

1. Filter responses that are only in the United States (country is returned in JSON)
2. Get the lat/long data and save those into the listing model

services.py

```py
import requests

def get_location(location):
    url = 'https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json'
    params = {'q': location, 'key': '***', 'language': 'en', 'pretty': 1}
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    locations = r.json()
    return locations
```

this gets me a response such as:

```
{
  "documentation": "https://opencagedata.com/api",
  ...
  "results": [
    {
      ...
      "components": {
        ...
        "_type": "city",
        "city": "Miami",
        ...
        "country": "USA",
        "country_code": "us",
        "state": "Florida",
        "state_code": "FL"
      },
      ...
      "formatted": "Miami, FL, United States of America",
      "geometry": {
        "lat": 25.7742658,
        "lng": -80.1936589
      }
    },
    ...
}
```

** EDIT **

I need to refine this question a bit. With what I have had answered so far here is where I am at:

views.py:

I am getting a string from the user submitted form which will be either a city-state or zipcode. What I want to do is query the API with this string, return a single variable which will be a combination of the `geometry lat & long`.

views.py

```
def post(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = postListing()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = postListing(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           ...
           title = form.cleaned_data['title']
           location = ?

           newPost = Listing.objects.create(title=title, location=location...)
```

What I am struggling with is:

- removing all non-US results
- grab first result of the refined data
- combine `geometry lat` & `geometry long` into one item to be saved as `location`
- I want to store only the first valid result into the new post, rather than create a post for each valid result

Comment: when you do `r.json()` you're actually getting a python object (list or dict). So `locations['results']` will give you the list of results and `[result for result in locations['results'] if result['components']['country'] == "USA"]` would give you just the results in the USA.

Comment: @dirkgroten and this returns `result` as a dictionary? How would I get the first occurrence? I am guessing I can then do something like `listing_city: result['components']['city']` in my views.py and pass that to the model to save via forms.py?

Comment: the python list comprehension example I gave you (`[result for ...]`) is indeed a list of dictionaries. So you can loop through it in a for-loop and for each element (let's say `result`) you can access the keys `"components"` and `"geometry"`, so yes, you can access `result['components']['city']`. I don't understand what you're trying to do in views.py and forms.py since you don't show any of it, but since this is just plain python, I don't see what's the issue in passing python objects around...

Comment: @dirkgroten I want to store city, state and lat + long as variables, which I can then store in the db. As I know how to do the CRUD process the clarification I was looking for was how exactly to turn the specific `result` items as variables. I'm coming from more of a PHP background so sorry if my terminology is off. Your edit to the comment was what I was looking for, I'll give that a try to see if I can get it to work and I'll update you.

Comment: again, if you have a `Model` called `Listing`, you can just create a new `Listing` for each `result`: `for result in results: Listing.objects.create(city=result['components']['city'], latitude=results['geometry']['lat'], ...)`. It's just simple plain python dicts and lists.

Comment: @dirkgroten I do not want a new listing for each result, instead I want to store the first US result as a field in a listing model. I have updated the question to hopefully be more clear. Thanks!

Comment: I think you got enough information now to easily solve your problem. I showed you how to filter results for only US results, since this is a list, `list[0]` gives you the first item and I just showed you how to get the lat from one item.

Comment: @dirkgroten I think I do have enough information and am attempting it now, but I can't accept a comment so if you can structure it as an answer so I can give credit I would appreciate it. I'll comment on any answer you give if further clarification is needed, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
locations = get_locations(location)
results = locations['result']
for result in results:
    print(result['geometry'])
```

Comment: I think combined with @dirkgroten's comment under my question that helps me start refining it, I've added a follow up question in the commentary that might help us refine my requirements further. Thank you!